# d3.event object in QtWebKit

Tags: d3.js, qtwebkit

I'm trying to use d3js inside a qtWebKit. In particular I've created the following test page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

rect.pane {
  cursor: move;
  pointer-events: all;
}

</style>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var margin = {top: 20, right: 60, bottom: 30, left: 20},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// svg
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .on("zoom", draw);

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "pane")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .call(zoom);


function draw() {
    console.log(d3.event);
}
</script>
```

The purpouse of this html code is to have a rect "firing" a scroll event and retrieve the scale value from the d3.event object, as explained in https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior.

If I load this example in chrome, looking at console I can see the object d3.event:

```
Object {type: "zoom", scale: 1.0511729090877093, translate: Array[2], sourceEvent: WheelEvent, target: function}
```

Now I've inserted this example into a qtWebKit widget; using a QMainWindow:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
  QMainWindow(parent),
  ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
  view(new QWebView(this))
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
  setCentralWidget(view);
  view->load(QUrl("qrc:/html/test.html"));

  QWebFrame *webFrame = view->page()->currentFrame();
  webFrame->addToJavaScriptWindowObject(QString("callback"), this);
}
```

with

```
Q_INVOKABLE void callbackScrollEvent(QString data);
```

and

```
void MainWindow::callbackScrollEvent(QString data)
{
qDebug() << "test" << data;
}
```

but the d3.event object is like empty:

```
test "[object Object]"
```

Is there something I'm missing?
I'm using Qt 4.8.4 but also using Qt 5.0.1 the issue is still present.

Answer (score 0):

In chrome you can see it is a object too. But the chrome developer tool will expand and display the structure of this object. So "[object Object]" is the right result in your code.

You can try to change the code

```
function draw() {
    console.log(d3.event);
}
```

to

```
function draw() {
    console.log(d3.map(d3.event));
}
```

This will transform the object to a map, the key is the object's properties. You may get the results like

```
u {type: "zoom", scale: 1.1809926614295303, translate: Array[2], sourceEvent: WheelEvent, target: function}
```

I am not sure what you will get in QtWebKit. If you cannot get you want, you can debug/check specific property by output it like following:

```
console.log("type:"+d3.event.type)
console.log("scale:"+d3.event.scale)
```

you will get

```
type:zoom fiddle.jshell.net:46
scale:1.1809926614295303
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Actually writing console.log(d3.event.scale) it returns correctly a float number in chrome, while using QtWebKit (modifying the function draw() in order to call the function callbackScrollEvent(QString data) it returns "NaN".

Comment: I guess returning a NaN cause the compiler think the draw() should return a numeric value. How did you modify the function draw()? Can you put your codes here?

Comment: sure: in QWebKit I use function draw() { callback.callbackScrollEvent("scale:"+d3.event.scale); }

Comment: so maybe you can try to delete "scale:" this string.

Comment: Actually I've tried to use d3.event.scale and Qt 5.0.1 and is working.